# error when creating glm for gtsummary table

Tags: linear-regression, glm

I am trying to build a logistic regression using the code below, but I encounter the error that I am unable to identify the cause of! I have compared the contents of my df to the example used in a recent gtsummary seminar (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtsummary/vignettes/tbl_regression.html) and I can't find the cause.

***Error in glm(disease_present ~ disease_cat, sex, age, data = df,  :
'weights' must be a numeric vector***

**Code**

```
mod <- glm(disease_present ~ disease_cat, sex, age, 
           data = df, family = binomial)
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      disease_cat = structure(
        c(
          7L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          5L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          3L,
          2L,
          2L,
          5L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          2L,
          8L,
          2L,
          8L,
          2L,
          7L,
          2L,
          7L,
          2L,
          7L,
          8L,
          8L,
          2L,
          2L,
          7L,
          2L,
          7L,
          7L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          5L,
          5L
        ),
        .Label = c(
          "breast",
          "prostate",
          "colorectal",
          "lung",
          "melanoma",
          "bladder",
          "pancreatic",
          "endometrial"
        ),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      disease_present = c(
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1
      ),
      sex = structure(
        c(
          2L,
          2L,
          1L,
          2L,
          1L,
          2L,
          1L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          1L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          1L,
          1L
        ),
        .Label = c("female", "male"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      age = c(
        18,
        41,
        40,
        45,
        48,
        25,
        50,
        56,
        45,
        46,
        45,
        28,
        40,
        50,
        25,
        50,
        40,
        40,
        40,
        40,
        50,
        50,
        29,
        26,
        8,
        55,
        60,
        40,
        35,
        40,
        22,
        45,
        10,
        45,
        14,
        21,
        45,
        53,
        55,
        18,
        45,
        18,
        35,
        53,
        45,
        45,
        54,
        48,
        30,
        44
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-50L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

Comment: `glm(disease_present ~ disease_cat, sex, age, data = df)` when you are using commans you are saying the `sex` varable is a weight and it cannot be a character it has to be a numeric. If you want these to be covariates your code should look like this `glm(disease_present ~ disease_cat+sex+ age, data = df)` if you want logistic regression please look into the `family=` argument of `glm()`

Comment: also I removed the gtsummary tag because your error is related to glm and not gtsummary